# Karma accumulation by violence against cows

Tags: krishna, karma, goddess, non-vegetarian, cows

Does killing a cow accumulate karmas equivalent to suffering those many lives equivalent to the number of hairs on the cow? 
(Hairs on a typical cow are millions/trillions in numbers)

Is there any such boon to cows/curse to cow killers?

I was informed this fact is based on the scriptures by my Guru once, so needed clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**. A person who kills cow has to rot in hell for as many years as there are hairs on the body of the cow.

> He, who, without being checked by the restraints of the scriptures, sells a cow, or kills one, or eats the flesh of a cow, or they, who, for the sake of wealth, suffer a person to kill kine,--all these, viz., he that kills, **he that eats, and he that permits the slaughter,--rot in hell for as many years as there are hairs on the body of the cow so slain.**
>
> [Anushasan Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b039.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I believe in the above info_source from  Mahabharata - epic written as it is in one go by the foremost remembered GOD SRI GANESHJI while being narrated by GURUDEV VED VYASJI.